# displaying no. of employees in a department using anonymous block

Tags: oracle

Create an anonymous block that will display the number of employees of the department number specified (using a substitution variable). Display the department name as well.

I've tried it but I don't understand why it does not run, here's my code:

```
DECLARE 
dep_id NUMBER :=depid;
dep_name VARCHAR2(20);
emp_id NUMBER;

BEGIN
SELECT department_id, department_name
INTO dep_id, dep_name
FROM departments 
WHERE department_id = dep_id;

SELECT count(employee_id), department_id
INTO emp_id, dep_id
FROM employees
WHERE employee_id = department_id
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(count(employee_id));

EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘No such department');
 END
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve by these? `WHERE employee_id = department_id` and `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(count(employee_id));`?

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into performance issues and what's the best way of doing it, it seems that you have to fix some issues:

1) `dep_id NUMBER :=depid;` - where does `depid` come from ?
if you're using sqlplus then you can do

```
dep_id NUMBER := &depid;
```

This will prompt the user for an input for depid.

2) `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (COUNT (employee_id));` - `COUNT (employee_id)` is part of the sql query, you can't just "call" it from your plsql code. 
What you should do is use the `emp_id` variable which you selected `COUNT (employee_id)` into it:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (emp_id);
```